# difficulty of lid driven cavity simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

Many people do lid driven cavity simulation, but most people don't get correct results. Many wrong attempts give an overall spinning motion of the fluid, without corner vortices. What's the reason of not getting corner vortices?

Comment: Probably not having a fine enough mesh or neglecting inertia.

Comment: by inertia do u mean the Dv/Dt term, dv/dt (d: partial), or the v*grad(v) term?

Comment: Well, the lid-driven flow is steady state, so the partial term is zero.

Comment: assume i'm simulating the transient evolution. plus, steady state approaches r not legitimate reasons to not c corner vortices

Comment: I don't follow this question.  You should see corner vortices in your simulation.

Comment: Related on [lid driven cavities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461782/25301).

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks, tho hasn't resolved my query still

Comment: @feynman wasn't intended to answer it, just a related question I found as I was scrolling through